# Spring data JPA: Log datasource used in transaction in case of AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using AbstractRoutingDataSource to achieve read replica connection as mentioned in below link:
https://vladmihalcea.com/read-write-read-only-transaction-routing-spring/

I want to print the transaction boundary and for that, I have added the below properties in the application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.orm.jpa: DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction: DEBUG
```

With this the transaction boundary related logs are getting printed properly as below:
e.g.

```
o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name
 o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1338079933<open>)] for JPA transaction
o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name 
 o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1161368013<open>)] for JPA transaction 
 o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1161368013<open>)]  
o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1161368013<open>)] after transaction
```

Along with this, I also want to **print the data source or hikari pool name** that is used in transaction. i.e. any information that can identify which data source is used by this transaction.

Comment: You can add logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE and then select the logger you are interested in

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have already added both logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig: DEBUG
and logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari: TRACE . But I don't see any log which shows which pool is used :( .

Comment: Pool configurations are printed with these logs, I want to know the pool from which the connection is fetched for a particular transaction

Comment: Why do you want to know that? This is given by the configuration

Comment: I am using AbstractRoutingDataSource, which picks up the reader or writer data source based on the "readOnly" attribute to @Transactional. Depending on valud of propagation property it may or may not consider the the readOnly flag. In my tests, I want to confirm right data source is picked up.